# Can't close/end TLS Connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

I get a connection through `conn = TLS.connect` and I can see this connection on the server end. Then I call `conn.end()` but still the connection doesn't die. The server will have this extra connection until I kill my node server..

Any ideas on how to kill the server?

Comment: Code? Errors? Evidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there was more in the code that was keeping connecting persistent..